# Simple Fermat Factorization Example

Tags: factoring

I'm trying to understand this example from wikipedia's [Fermat's factorization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method).

> For example, to factor N = 5959, the first try for a is the square root of 5959 rounded up to the next integer, which is 78. Then, we try 79.

```
Try:    1       2      3
a      78      79      80
b^2    125     282     441
b      11.18   16.79   21
```

> The third try produces the perfect square of 441. So, a = 80, b = 21, and the factors of 5959 are a - b = 59 and a + b = 101.

At this point, I understand the `80^2 - 5959 = 441`, which is perfect square of 21.

At this point I'm not sure what to do.

Given this work so far, what are the final steps? And, what do we get from completing the final steps?

Comment: No one would use this method for factoring $5959$, which is just $59\cdot 100+59=59(100+1)=59\cdot 101$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$80^2-5959=441$ rearranges to $80^2-21^2=5959$.

Then $5959=(80-21)(80+21)$.

Comment: Thanks. As a follow-up, (1) at what point, i.e. at what `a`, can we safely know that `N` is a prime? And, (2), what if `N` has more than 2 prime factors? In the above case `N = 5959`, you showed that its factors are `(80-21)(80+21)`. What if there were more factors?

Comment: It is certainly possible that in Fermat's factorization method, the resulting factors can themselves be factored further.

Comment: Understood, thanks. And, lastly, can you please look at my (1) comment question?

Comment: In the case that $N$ is prime, Fermat's factorization method continues until the factorization $N=N\cdot 1$ is found.  This will occur when $a=\frac{N+1}{2}$.

Comment: thank you. And, based, `is based on the representation of an odd integer as the difference of two squares:` -[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method), then Fermat's method does **not** apply to even #s?

Comment: Typically you wouldn't apply Fermat to even numbers--just start by factoring out any powers of $2$ that you can, until you are left with just an odd part to factor.  (Fermat doesn't work on '2 times odd' it does work on multiples of 4.)